# How can I form MySQL query algorithm to add columns to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like below.

**sentences**

```
     +--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id     | language | text                                                                  |
     +--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | 519125 | epo      | Mia onklo aĉetis por mi horloĝon kiu estas tre akurata.               |
     | 519126 | epo      | Mi ne povas akcepti vian donacon.                                     |
     | 519127 | uig      | ئۇ پۈتۈن مەملىكەتنى ئارىلاپ چىقماقچى.                                   |
     | 519128 | eng      | She's planning to travel the entire country.                          |
     | 519129 | eng      | He's planning to travel the entire country.                           |
     | 519130 | uig      | تاڭنىڭ ئالدىدا قاراڭغۇسى بار.                                          |
     | 519131 | epo      | Li trovas kritikindan en ĉio kion mi faras.                           |
     +--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and

**links**

```
     +------------+--------------+
     | sentenceId | translatedId |
     +------------+--------------+
     |     124665 |      1972285 |
     |     124666 |       279328 |
     |     124666 |       957578 |
     |     124667 |       279327 |
     |     124667 |       440607 |
     +------------+--------------+
```

They consist of millions of lines. I want to add two more columns to the second table after `sentenceId` and `translatedId` like:

```
       +------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
       | sentenceId | languageId1 | translatedId | languageId2 |
       +------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

In the above table **(sentenceId languageId1)** and **(translatedId  languageId2)** are pairs indeed. `languageId1` and `languageId2` show language shorthands of `sentenceId` and `translatedId` respectively. But language shorthands of sentenceId and translatedId defined in the first table in the language column. In order to form that table each `sentenceId` and translatedId values must be looked up in the first table and found language shorthands must be replaced in `languageId1` and `languageId2`. So how can I form above table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add your result to a new table (you need to create it before)

```
INSERT INTO mynewtable 
SELECT LINKS.sentenceId, SRC_SENT.language AS srcLanguage,
       LINKS.translatedId, DST_SENT.language AS dstLanguage
FROM LINKS
INNER JOIN sentences SRC_SENT ON (LINKS.sentenceId = SRC_SENT.id)
INNER JOIN sentences DST_SENT ON (LINKS.translatedId = DST_SENT.id)
```

If you want to add columns to the table links, you have to modify its structure before, and then update it.

Comment: thank you very much for responding. I still can not get my head around it, SRC_LANG.language is sentences.language but translatedId also must look up its corresponding value in sentences.language column. I fiddled with it a bit, this one works halfway but it's missing languageId2 column. Here 


     `SELECT links.sentenceId, sentences.language AS languageId1, links.translatedId
      FROM links
      INNER JOIN sentences
      ON links.sentenceId=sentences.id;`

Comment: @kenn Sorry, I forgot to use aliases for the two language fields, corrected now. Try the updated one.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, I feel dumb, "SRC_LANG.language", "DST_LANG.language", are they new databases? or do they substitute for   abstract algorithm?

Comment: @kenn And I mistyped the aliases in the `SELECT` as well. You need to inner join twice on `sentences`, one for source language and one for destination language. Obviously you need to inner join two different instances of `sentences` table, so you create 2 alias.